# Can I pass a variable in a method to a textview in an adapter?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I want to pass

```
int count = cursor.getCount();
```

from

```
public List<Products> getAllProducts() {
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_ID,
                COLUMN_BARCODE,
                COLUMN_NAME,
                COLUMN_OPRICE,
                COLUMN_SPRICE,
                COLUMN_XPDATE
        };

        String sortOrder =
                COLUMN_ID + " DESC";
        List<Products> productList = new ArrayList<Products>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCT,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                COLUMN_NAME,
                null,
                sortOrder);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Products product = new Products();
                product.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID))));
                product.setBarcode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BARCODE)));
                product.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
                product.setOprice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_OPRICE)));
                product.setSprice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SPRICE)));
                product.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_XPDATE)));
                productList.add(product);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        **int count = cursor.getCount();**
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return productList;
    }
```

to a textview in an adapter

```
holder.total.setText("counts");
```

Adapter

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder>{
    private List<Products> listProducts;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    public ProductsAdapter(List<Products> listProducts) {
        this.listProducts= listProducts;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.products_list, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(listProducts.get(position).getName());
        holder.total.setText("counts");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listProducts.size();
    }

    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name, total;
        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.available);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `total` related to a particular row in the adapter?

Comment: Do you want the same number in all the items of the RecyclerView?

Comment: its a count of rows where product name = name
no @forpas it show only display the number of rows for a particular product

Comment: `int count = cursor.getCount();` returns the number of all the rows of the table. Each row of the table is a single product.

Comment: Yes @forpas I just want to pass the variable to the adapter for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest you make the variable you want to use global(eg define it outside the method) then instantiate it inside the methode then call the class that has the variable you want to pass

for example

```
Myclass class = new Myclass()
Int count = class.count
```

then convert the Int to a string coz textviews only take in String
eg.`String countSt = String.ValueOf(count)`
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
int count = cursor.getCount();
```

the number of rows contained in the cursor is assigned  to the variable `count`.
These rows are all added to the list `productList`.
So, actually you don't need the variable `count` because you can get the same number just by getting the size of the list.

This list is passed in your adapter class as `listProducts`, so get its size and show it inside the `TextView`:

```
holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(listProducts.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas my reputation is too low for me to vote

Comment: Is it possible to sort by name in the adapter instead of the databasehelper class?

Comment: @znovativ you would have to create a custom comperator inside your Products class and then use Collections.sort() inside your adapter class. You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449256/how-to-sort-in-a-listview-with-a-custom-adapter.